# Getting Place data from gedodata API

Tags: android, search

I have place Id, I am using geodata api to get place details. how to build googleApi client for that. I did like this.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API).build()
```

IN Onconnected method, I did following

```
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                        if (places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            final Place myPlace = places.get(0);
                            Log.i("mytag", "Place found: " + myPlace.getName() + myPlace.getLatLng().toString());
                        }
                        places.release();
                    }
                });

    }
```

I am not getting the result, how to  build googleApi client to geodata Api ?

I used server key in manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the official [document](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/place-details) of google for getting place details by id/get user current place/place picker widget etc.

Setting up google api client [link](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start).

Follow this [blog](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/google-play-services-using-the-places-api--cms-23715) too for simple explanations.

And you can also get it by using the API https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJrTLr-GyuEmsRBfy61i59si0&key=YOUR_API_KEY without configuring google play service.

[visit](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id) for more.

Comment: In android manifest file i used server key , In url mentioned above we have to use server key .  but when we are accessing through app, we have to mention android key in  for google  places and maps v2 ,

Comment: how do i get an api key? couldnt find answer on here